# Pandas : Comparing values of a matrix stocked in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

for a class project I have to find all passenger doing a return flight
After cleaning my data I obtain this : [image: DataFrame]
What I want to do is check for each travel ('voyage') if the corresponding matrix values are inverted. If they are, consider it a return flight. For example: travel 0 = [[5,8],[8,5]] = a return flight, while travel 1 [[1,2],[3,8]] isn't.
The challenge is that we can't use a for loop or an if
Thanks for your time

Tried to stock this into Numpy arrays but without a for loop couldn't manage to

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of your idea with `numpy` arrays. Just checking is transposed matrix is equal to itself. Technically no `for` loops are used.

```
def is_symmetric(matrix):
    matrix = np.array(matrix)
    return (matrix == matrix.T).all()

is_symmetric([[5,8],[8,5]]), is_symmetric([[1,2],[3,8]])

# >>> (True, False)
```

Here's how to apply the function to a dataframe column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "passenger_id": [1, 2],
    "matrix": [[[5,8],[8,5]], [[1,2],[3,8]]]
})
df["is_return"] = df.matrix.apply(is_symmetric)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   passenger_id            matrix  is_return
0             1  [[5, 8], [8, 5]]       True
1             2  [[1, 2], [3, 8]]      False
```

UPD: you can even do this using one big transposition of the whole column, but first you'll have to convert pandas Series of lists to `np.array`:

```
arr = df["matrix"].values.tolist()
(arr == np.transpose(arr, axes=[0, 2, 1])).all(axis=(1, 2))

# >>> array([ True, False])
```